# Handling optional Route path parameter (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, frontend

Basically I have a login route where I wanna be able to declare an **optional path parameter**.

In my React Router, I have the following path for login:

```
<Route exact path={routingService.loginUrl(":returnUrl?")} render={Auth} />
```

Where **routingService** is declared like this:

```
const routingService = {
  loginUrl: (returnUrl?: string) => `/login/?${encodeURIComponent(returnUrl || "")}`,
};
```

I tried this way but it didn't work. It redirects me to the NotFound page instead.

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
```

But when I manually change the path to

```
<Route exact path="/login/:returnUrl?" render={Auth} />
```

...it does work, but I want to organize the path by using the one (**loginUrl**) we have in **routingService**.

This might be really simple to fix, but I'm kinda struggling. Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: `(returnUrl?: string) => \`/login/?${encodeURIComponent(returnUrl || "")}\`` appends the `returnUrl` where a queryString would be. Remove the `?` from the string template. Can you be more specific about what isn't working? Is there an error? You probably don't need to URI encode your route path parameter.

Comment: @DrewReese it doesn't throw an error, it just redirects you to the NotFound page (path equals to *) instead. I already tried to remove the ? from the string template, but it didn't solve it

Comment: I don't understand the complexity/abstraction here, why can't `routingService.loginUrl` not just return the string `"/login/:returnUrl?"` for the route's `path` value? Do you have more than one login route that requires calling the second path segment a different name? Can you provide a more [complete/comprehensive code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or also a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I also don't understant why I'm having this issue. And no, I don't have more than one login route besides this one

Comment: @DrewReese sure! As soon as I run a CodeSandbox demo, I will let you know. Thank you for now, Drew!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why removing the extraneous `"?"` in the middle of the login path isn't working for you. The `encodeURIComponent` is certainly incorrect. You don't need to URLencode the paths you are trying to match by.

```js
const routingService = {
  loginUrl: (returnUrl) => `/login/?${encodeURIComponent(returnUrl || "")}`,
};

console.log(routingService.loginUrl(":returnUrl?")); // "/login/?%3AreturnUrl%3F"
```

Remove the extra question mark that is placing the `returnURL` in the queryString portion of the URL, and remove the `encodeURIComponent` function call, just return the `returnUrl` value.

```js
const routingService = {
  loginUrl: (returnUrl) => `/login/${returnUrl || ""}`,
};

console.log(routingService.loginUrl(":returnUrl?")); // "/login/:returnUrl"
```

```
const routingService = {
  loginUrl: (returnUrl?: string) => `/login/${returnUrl || ""}`
};
```

...

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path={routingService.loginUrl(":returnUrl?")}
    render={(props) => <Auth />}
  />
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Working sandbox demo

[image: Edit handling-optional-route-path-parameter-react]

Answer (score 1):

Is that because of extra `?` in the function?

**Corrected one:**

```js
const routingService = {
  loginUrl: (returnUrl?: string) => `/login/${returnUrl || ""}`,
};
```

**Edit:**

`encodeURIComponent(":returnUrl?")` gives us `'%3AreturnUrl%3F'`, so it may not work. Maybe try without `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: I already tried to remove it before, but it didn't solve

Comment: Maybe without `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: It doesn't work either, Shri